# Does both a CloseableHttpClient and CloseableHttpResponse need to be closed explicitly

Tags: java

I have the following method, which issues a `HTTP` `POST` request.

It returns a `CloseableHttpResponse` so any code calling it can obtain status code, response body etc.

I'm trying to understand, does both the:

- `CloseableHttpClient client`
- `CloseableHttpResponse closeableHttpResponse`

need to be closed? Or does closing one, close the other?

```
..
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;

public static CloseableHttpResponse post(final String restEndpoint, final String data, final Header[] headers) throws Exception {
    final URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder(restEndpoint);
    final HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uriBuilder.build());
    httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    httpPost.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store");

    if (data != null) {
        httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(data));
    }

    if (headers != null) {
        for (Header header : headers) {
            httpPost.setHeader(header);
        }
    }

    final CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
            .setSSLSocketFactory(createSSLFactory())
            .setSSLHostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier())
            .build();

    final CloseableHttpResponse closeableHttpResponse = client.execute(httpPost);
    final int statusCode = closeableHttpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    logger.debug(Optional.empty(), statusCode, httpPost.toString());

    return closeableHttpResponse;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* the `CloseableHttpResponse` will need to be closed manually every individual request.

There are a couple ways of doing that.

With a try/catch/finally block:

```
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;

import java.io.IOException;

public class CloseableHttpClientWithTryCatchFinally {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

        URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder("https://www.google.com/");

        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uriBuilder.build());

        CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().build();

        CloseableHttpResponse response = null;

        try {
            response = client.execute(httpGet);

            response.getEntity().writeTo(System.out);

        } catch (IOException e) {

            System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {

            if (response != null) {
                response.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think a better answer is to use the [try-with-resources statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html):

```
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;

import java.io.IOException;

public class CloseableHttpClientTryWithResources {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

        URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder("https://www.google.com/");

        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uriBuilder.build());

        CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().build();

        try (CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet)) {

            response.getEntity().writeTo(System.out);

        } catch (IOException e) {

            System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In general, I have seen people just create one `CloseableHttpClient` for their application and then just reuse that instance throughout their app.  If you are only going to be using one, or a few instances, over and over, then no, I don't think you should have to close them.  However, if you are going to be creating new instances of `CloseableHttpClient` over and over, then yes, you will need to close them.